# Eslint: Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression

Tags: javascript, eslint

I have a string variable that comes from a Web API request. The variable may contain the string `"true"` or the string `"false"`, or be empty.

I convert this value from string into a real Boolean since `'true' != true`:

```
[
  request.body.truncateEntities === 'true' ? true : false,
  request.body.truncateDomains === 'true' ? true : false,
]
```

Both these lines trigger an eslint warning:

> Unnecessary use of boolean literals in conditional expression.

Is there really a better way to write this code?

I'm using eslint 2.0 (the one that's built into Visual Studio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You can directly write:

```
[
  request.body.truncateEntities === 'true',
  request.body.truncateDomains === 'true',
]
```

Because a comparision expression (like `request.body.truncateEntities === 'true'`) evaluates to boolean anyways, the ternary conditional expression is unnecessary.

Comment: Happens to the best of us :)